# updating the column of a table with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called person there are about 3 million rows

I have added a column called company_type_id whose default value is 0

now i want to update the value of  company_type_id to 1

where person_id from 1 to 212465
and value of company_type_id to 8 where person_id from 256465 to 656464

how can i do this

I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in one update statement:

```
update person
set company_type_id = 1
where 
(person_id >= 1 and person_id <= 212465) or
(company_type_id = 8 and person_id >= 256465 and person_id <= 656464)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update person set company_type_id=1 where person_id>=1 and person_id<=212465;
```

I am sure you'll make the second update query by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Two SQLs:

1:

```
UPDATE person
SET company_type_id = 1
WHERE person_id BETWEEN 1 AND 212465
```

2:

```
UPDATE person
SET company_type_id = 8
WHERE person_id BETWEEN 256465 AND 656464
```